# Find the cube roots of $ -8 i $ and plot them on a plane.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, polar-coordinates, angle

I can’t figure out the angle of this equation.

I set it up like this:
$$
z^{3} = 0 - 8 i.
$$
I find that the $ r $-value is $ 2 $, but when I try to find the angle, I’m stuck. I can’t divide by $ 0 $, so where did I go wrong? Or what am I missing to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without DeMoivre and trigonometry if you’ve observed that $i^3=-i$ and that therefore $(2i)^3=-8i$. Thus $X^3+8i$, as the difference of two cubes, factors in the way that I hope you already know, $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$, giving
$$
X^3+8i=(X-2i)(X^2+2iX-4)\,,
$$
and the quadratic part you can run the Quadratic Formula on.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{You want to use Demoivre. So you have,} \ \ z^3=-8i \Rightarrow 8(\cos(\frac{-\pi}{2})+i\sin(\frac{-\pi}{2}))$$

$$\text{By Demoivre}: z = 2\{\cos(\frac{\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi k}{3})+i\sin(\frac{\frac{-\pi}{2}+2\pi k}{3})\}, \ \text{for $k=0,1,2$}$$

Comment: why is the angle -pi/2? how did you come to that conclusion.

Comment: $-8i$ lies on the negative part of the $y$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $-8i$ lies on the negative imaginary axis, so you will have trouble computing the angle as an arctangent. But, thinking about the geometry, isn't the angle just $-\pi/2$?

Comment: couldn't it be 3pi/2?

Comment: @Joshhw both $3 \pi /2$ and $- \pi/2$ will work equally well for the purposes of this problem; it just depends on how you like to think of it.

Comment: @Joshhw: That's one possible argument. The argument isn't unique. Once you have determined one of them, you know them all (they different by integral multiples of $2\pi$). To find all of the roots, you need all of the possible arguments, so it doesn't matter which one you choose to start with.

Comment: @Rod: There is no restriction. The argument can be chosen in $(-\infty,\infty)$ and you will arrive at the same set of roots.

Comment: You are correct @MPW

Comment: @Rod: Yes, but I understand your point. If OP were looking for some sort of "principal value", it would be important to restrict the possible values of "the" argument.